# Enabling Folder as one of default content item views

Tags: plone

I have nested folder structure.

I'd like to have the splash page of a folder (site section) come from another folder (blog).

However, by default Plone does not seem to offer this functionality. Is it possible to enable default content view behavior for folders in the settings or does it require monkey-patching?

What pitfalls enabled this might include (regarding breadcrumbs, paths, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to:

ZMI -> portal_properties -> site_properties

edit the property `default_page_types` and add a new line with "Folder".
This will allow you to select a subfolder as default view for your folder. I made a small test and I can't see any pitfall, it behaves just like any other default view.